# My java program to find armstrong number is not working

Tags: java

here's my program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class armstrongno {

    int num;
    int sum;
    int cube;
    int dig;
    int temp;

    public void method() throws IOException {
        dig = 0;
        cube = 0;
        sum = 0;
        num = 0;
        temp = 0;
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        num = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
        temp = num;
        while (temp == 0) {
            dig = temp % 10;
            cube = dig * dig * dig;
            sum = sum + cube;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if (sum == num) {
            System.out.println("Armstrong number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not an Armstrong number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the main method?

Answer (score 2):

```
while(temp==0)// this will execute when temp=0 else never execute. 
{
    dig=temp%10;
    cube=dig*dig*dig;
    sum=sum+cube;
    temp=temp/10;
}
```

So never  go inside `if(sum==num)`. So you are getting `else` part as out put.

Change your code as follows.

```
while (temp > 0) {
        dig = temp % 10;
        cube = dig * dig * dig;
        sum = sum + cube;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
```

Comment: it dooesn't work that way also

Answer (score 1):

`while(temp==0)`

This will never execute if `temp` is not zero.

You might want to do:

`while(temp > 0)`

---

A tip that can sometimes save your life: Use a debugger.

Comment: and thanks a lot, your editing greatly helped :)

Comment: @user2086999 I'm glad it helped you :) You should use a debugger, it saves a lot of time and efforts.